# jquery effect does not want to work in google chrome. what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I'm trying to make a fadeIn() and slideDown() in jquery, but it does not want to work in chrome. Here's the code

```
$(function (){

    $('#wrap h1').hide().slideDown(3000)
    $('.circles_1 img').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(5000)

})
```

and here's the html code of it :

```
<section id="circles">

<figure class="circles_1"><a href="photoshop.html">image 1<img        src="images/photoshop.png"/></a></figure>

<figure class="circles_1"><a href="illustrator.html">image 2<img src="images/illustrator.png"/></a></figure>

<figure class="circles_1"><a href="indesign.html">image 3<img src="images/indesign.png"/></a></figure>

<figure class="circles_1"><a href="websites.html">image 4<img src="images/websites.png"/></a></figure>


</section>
```

Comment: is this not what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/EakzN/ Seems to work when you comment out first line of jQuery. There is no id "wrap" in your HTML provided.

Comment: your first animation is trying to hide and show the element at the same time

Comment: Ditto, this is kind of working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/Qpr79/

Comment: missing semi-colons too

Comment: @AurélienOoms semi-colons are _optional_ in most situations - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 0):

Tested in [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/F3D9e/9/) and seems working fine, make sure you have JQuery Library link included.

Answer (score 0):

Import jquery 
    < script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >

and then try to load the function after the Dom is ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#wrap h1').hide().slideDown(3000)**;**
    $('.circles_1 img').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(5000)**;**
});
```

And dont forget the **;**

Cheers.

Comment: Semi-colons are optional in most situations - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi